# Batch file to terminate all instances of IExplore.exe

Tags: batch-file

Sometimes IE freezes up and I have to open the Task Manager, right click the process and choose End Process to get it to really close.

If I have a lot open, I have to find the right one to end. I want a batch file command I can run to just terminate them all.

I tried using taskkill as described [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/), but that does not terminate a frozen IE like the "End Process" button does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will kill all instances of IE

```
taskkill /im iexplore.exe /f
```